# How to find an exponential variable?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

What is the way to solve a simple equation of this type?

$$x ^ 4 = 1.25$$

Update: I should have asked, how to calculate N'th root in a calculator?

Comment: Closely related question to help guide you to the answer: Do you know how to solve $x^2 = 1.25$? What do you do to solve this for $x$?

Comment: The answers will be the $4$'th roots of $1.25$.  In general, solving for $x$ in $x^n=b$ with $n$ a positive integer will be the [$n$'th roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) of $b$.  If you are working in the complex numbers there are $n$ different $n$'th roots of every number except zero (*see [De Moivre's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers)*).

Comment: Maybe by changing the name to $X=x^2$ helps more.

Comment: Are you familiar the formula ? $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, I know it's the 4th root, but I don't know how to calculate it. Most calculators have y^x and 2Vy (square root) button, but no xVy button. How can I achieve this with a calculator / any programming language?

Comment: @lonestudent I remember it from years ago, but not sure how to apply it to my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt[4]{x}=x^{\frac 14}=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$ so just hit the square root button twice or use `y^x` with $x=0.25$.

For the n-th root $\sqrt[n]{x}=x^{\frac 1n}$ so you can use the `y^x` button with $x=\frac 1n$.

(it can be challenging if your calculator doesn't accept parenthesis to enter $\frac 1n$, in that case you calculate it in advance and enter the decimal value, e.g. $0.33333333333$ for $\frac 13$).

When $n$ is a power of $2$ then you can just hit square root as many times as desired, e.g. $8=2^3$ so $\sqrt[8]{x}=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}$ three times.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4=a, a\in\mathbb R^{+}$$

$$\implies( x^2)^2-(\sqrt a)^2=0$$

$$\implies (x^2-\sqrt a)(x^2+\sqrt a)=0$$

$$\implies (x^2-(\sqrt[4]{a})^2)(x^2-(i\sqrt[4]{a})^2)=0$$

$$ \implies (x-\sqrt[4]{a})(x+\sqrt[4]{a})(x-i\sqrt[4]{a})(x+i\sqrt[4]{a})=0$$

I leave it here for you.

Comment: Thanks!  Regarding the practical calculation, while my example can be solved by square rooting twice in a calculator, do you how can we do Nth root in a calculator?